# System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, resources

I have a Resource text file `setupfile.txt` I have added to my project, and I have a method that attempts to read it for a connection string like this:

```
public static string GetConnectionString()
{
    StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users..."); // this doesn't cause any errors
    StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(Properties.Resources.setupfile); // this doesn't
    mySqlConnectionString = rdr.ReadToEnd();
    rdr.Close();
    return mySqlConnectionString;
}
```

As I said before, all the file contains is a connection string and 3 numbers:

```
server=localhost;database=dcim;uid=root;pwd=LlmD62jL;
1,10,2
```

However when I attempted to run a test to see if the file contained text, I got the excpetion:

> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path

I don't know what's going on?

Comment: Is there any reason for using a text file for the connection string? Can't you use a config file? Like web.config or app.config?

Comment: use the web.config file or app.config file to store connectionstrings.

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722455/read-text-file-from-c-sharp-resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StreamReader` constructor expects the file path, not the file content. I guess you're passing file content as string that's why you get exception due to invalid chars in file(may be due to `;`).

All you need is

```
mySqlConnectionString  = Properties.Resources.setupfile;
```

Also I strongly recommend you to use [App.Config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) file for ConnectionString.